# Showing two RelativeLayouts in a LinearLayout not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to display two RelativeLayouts in a LinearLayout, however the best result I'm getting is getting one of the two displayed.

```
    final LinearLayout layoutMain = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(layoutMain);

    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    RelativeLayout layoutAll = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, null);
    final RelativeLayout menuLayout = (RelativeLayout)inflate.inflate(
            R.layout.bottom_menu, null);
    menuLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    layoutMain.addView(layoutAll);
    layoutMain.addView(menuLayout);
```

layoutAll is showing, and if I change the order of the addView lines, then menuLayout is showing. So far I've tried different layout parameters (MATCH_PARENT for layoutAll or menuLayout and even both). Any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with setting height of layoutAll to WRAP_CONTENT? Alternatively you can try with assigning weight to layoutAll and menulayout as 3 and 1 respectively

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the tips. I've set the weight of layoutAll and menuLayout to 3 and 1, I've also set height of layoutAll to WRAP_CONTENT and it was not working, however I changed layout_height of layoutAll to match_parent and it is working. But now I have another issue, I have a button in layoutAll, when I align it to the bottom of the layout I'm not able anymore to see menuLayout. Any idea ? Thanks again.